# Generating packed template from Weblogic Admin Server Dynamically fails

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a weblogic domain (i.e. server1) that manages multiple managed servers (i.e. server2) on remote machines on which the admin server does not reside.  I am trying to use WLST in online mode to dynamically pack the domain on the Admin Server into a JAR and transfer it to the managed server, but it fails due to CIE ConfigHelper service not being availble.  I've tried to find a reference to this service with no lunck.

Here is the log of the output:

```
Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

Connecting to t3://admin:7001 with userid admin ...
Successfully connected to Admin Server "wladmin_server" that belongs to domain "qa".

Warning: An insecure protocol was used to connect to the
server. To ensure on-the-wire security, the SSL port or
Admin port should be used instead.

Location changed to serverRuntime tree. This is a read-only tree with DomainMBean as the root.
For more help, use help('domainConfig')

CIE ConfigHelper online service is not available.

Disconnected from weblogic server: wladmin_server
```

I'm doing this based on the following link https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLSTG/domains.htm#WLSTG406 , but it just doesn't seem to work.

I am using Weblogic 12c (12.1.3) running on RH Linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

pack and unpack scripts are working for us in similar scenario.
On admin server machine where domain is already created ,You can use this to pack/create managed server template :

```
   $WL_HOME/common/bin/pack.sh -domain=${DOMAIN_HOME} \
  -template=${DOMAIN_NAME}_managed_template.jar \
  -template_name="${DOMAIN_NAME}" \
  -template_author="YOU" \
  -template_desc="${DOMAIN_NAME}-managed-template" \
  -managed="true" \
  -log=logs/pack_managed_${DOMAIN_NAME}.log
```

Then copy managed server template to different machines and unpack there:

```
$WL_HOME/common/bin/unpack.sh  \
-domain=$DOMAIN_HOME \
-template=${DOMAIN_NAME}_managed_template.jar \
-overwrite_domain="true" \
-app_dir=$DOMAIN_HOME/../applications \
-log=logs/${DOMAIN_NAME}_creation.log
```

Comment: The pack/unpack command does work, but this means that I would have to pack on the admin server, then copy the template over to the managed server.  Now, based on the documentation there is supposed to be a way to have the pack be done on-the-fly using online WLST and then use it on the managed server.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered the same problem on my weblogic `(ver 12.1.3)`. The problem seems to appear only when the weblogic server is started using wlst.

When I started the weblogic using `startWeblogic.sh` file and run the domain template wlst script the error(CIE ConfigHelper online service is not available.) has disappeared, and I can see that the template is created successfully.

It seems like a bug in weblogic wlst.